# Where is the data stored in localhost?

Tags: node.js, database, server, localhost, web-development-server

i followed a tutorial and made a todo list web app using nodejs, express and ejs. after completing i used ngrok to make my localhost public so that i can share it with my friends, now i've realized that the tasks that i add on my todo list are saved in my server unless i restart it or close it completely. i want to know where the tasks which is a  is stored in my local machine, does nodejs store it, or its saved in the memory of my local machine, more importantly if its already being stored somewhere why do i have to worry about using a database server like mongodb or firebase? hope my question is clear.

Comment: You need to provide code, in order to check. What kind of storage you are using.

Comment: just plain html  <div class="box">
    <% for(var i = 0; i < newListItem.length; i++) { %>
    <% if(newListItem[i]){ %>
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <p> <%= newListItem[i] %> </p>
    </div>
    <% } %>
    <% } %>